# Editing Text in an Excel Column

Tags: excel, vba, string, edit

I have a very large set of data with long names containing one specific part that is useful to me for the organization. What I am trying to do is to search through the whole column and separate out just the part that I want. As an example here is one data point "190826_095630_3E_1". What I need is for the column to be reduced to the "3E" portion of this name. I use all the data in lists of 3E-3L, 4E-4L, 5E-5L etc all the way down. I have no idea where to even begin on this one, I usually try to do some code but I can't figure out where to start.

Expected results would be a vba code/macro that would take thousands of cells in column 1 with long names like "190826_095630_3E_1" and reduce the whole column down to "3E" so I can organize it and use it.

Comment: Read up on documentation about `Range` for determining what cells you want to test, `for` (or `foreach`) loops to iterate over them and text matching mechanisms such as but certainly not limited to `InStr`. In your case perhaps even regular epressions, they look scary but can be really handy. Without at least some code or demonstrable effort on your part, your question is destined to be voted away.

Comment: Text to columns - split on "_" and delete the columns you don't need?

Comment: another approach - look up `array` & `split`

Comment: Is 3E always in position 15-16? is it always the 3rd substring (separated by _'s)? Is there SOME rule to always find the 3E?